# Ignite SqlFieldsQuery specific keys

Tags: c++, ignite, gridgain

Using the ignite C++ API, I'm trying to find a way to perform an SqlFieldsQuery to select a specific field, but would like to do this for a set of keys.

One way to do this, is to do the SqlFieldsQuery like this,

```
SqlFieldsQuery("select field from Table where _key in (" + keys_string + ")")
```

where the `keys_string` is the list of the keys as a comma separated string.

Unfortunately, this takes a very long time compared to just doing `cache.GetAll(keys)` for the set of keys, `keys`.

Is there an alternative, faster way of getting a specific field for a set of keys from an ignite cache?

**EDIT:**

After reading the answers, I tried changing the query to:

```
auto query = SqlFieldsQuery("select field from Table t join table(_key bigint = ?) i on t._key = i._key")
```

I then add the arguments from my set of keys like this:

```
for(const auto& key: keys) query.AddArgument(key);
```

but when running the query, I get the error:

`Failed to bind parameter [idx=2, obj=159957, stmt=prep0: select field from Table t join table(_key bigint = ?) i on t._key = i._key {1: 159956}]`

Clearly, this doesn't work because there is only one '?'.

So I then tried to pass a `vector<int64_t>` of the keys, but I got an error which basically says that `std::vector<int64_t>` did not specialize the ignite `BinaryType`. So I did this as defined [here](https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/serialization). When calling e.g.

```
writer.WriteInt64Array("data", data.data(), data.size())
```

I gave the field a arbitrary name "data". This then results in the error:

`Failed to run map query remotely.`

Unfortunately, the C++ API is neither well documented, nor complete, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something or that the API does not allow for passing an array as argument to the `SqlFieldsQuery`.

Comment: You can't pass an array as a parameter in C++ yet. Why do you want to use queries, if you can use `GetAll()`?

Comment: I was told that querying for specific fields could be faster than getting the whole object, due to bandwidth limits.

Answer (score 1):

Query that uses `IN` clause doesn't always use indexes properly. The workaround for this is described here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-performance-and-debugging#sql-performance-and-usability-considerations

Also if you have an option to to `GetAll` instead and lookup by key directly, then you should use it. It will likely be more effective anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Query with operator "IN" will not always use indexes. As a workaround, you can rewrite the query in the following way:

```
select field from Table t join table(id bigint = ?) i on t.id = i.id
```

and then invoke it like:

```
    new SqlFieldsQuery(
      "select field from Table t join table(id bigint = ?) i on t.id = i.id")
       .setArgs(new Object[]{ new Integer[] {2, 3, 4} }))
```